# Conditional statement with empty string

Tags: python-3.x

Why does `'' and not '123'` evaluate to `''` instead of `False`, but `not '123' and ''` evaluates to `False` in Python 3.4.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical and/or operators stop evaluating terms (short-circuit) as soon as the answer is decided.

#### Examples with `and`

```
>>> '' and not '123'
''
```

The first one is false, so the `and` is short-circuited and the first one is returned.

```
>>> not '123' and ''
False
```

`not '123'` returns `False`.  Since that is false, the `and` is short-circuited and the result of `not '123'` one is returned.

For exactly the same reason, the following returns zero:

```
>>> 0 and '123'
0
```

And the following returns `[]`:

```
>>> [] and '123'
[]
```

#### Examples with `or`

```
>>> '' or '123'
'123'
>>> not '123' or 'Hi'
'Hi'
>>> '123' or 'Hi'
'123'
```

#### Documentation

This behavior is specified in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) where:

- `x or y` is defined as `if x is false, then y, else x`
- `x and y` is defined as `if x is false, then x, else y`
- `not x` is defined as `if x is false, then True, else False`

Comment: All this time I thought Python returns the boolean value of the result.

Comment: So `x or y or z or 0` works like `COALESCE(x, y, z, 0)` in SQL. Awesome.

Comment: Yes, similar.  COALESCE looks for the first non-null while the python `or` looks for the first argument that does not evaluate to `False`.  I just added a link to the docs which may help.